# c++ half library has lower precision for positive numbers

Tags: c++, precision

I know that I am using a capability not built into c++ however, this library seems to be so commonly used that I am surprised to see this error pop up.

For those of you who do not know about the library it can be found [here](http://half.sourceforge.net/). Essentially, it is supposed to allow the support of 16 bit floating point (lower precision) numbers.

My problem is that the precision of half floats appears to diminish for positive numbers.

In this code, I am generating a bunch of points to be rendered to the screen. {xs1, ys1} represents floating point precision calculation of sigmoid. {xs3, ys3} represents the values cast into floating point precision.

```
vector<float> xs1, ys1, xs3, ys3;
int res = 200000;
for (int i = 0; i < res; i++)
{
    float prec = float(i) / float(res);
    float fx = ((perc - 0.5) * 2.0)*8.0;
    half hx = half(fx);
    float fy = MFunctions::sigmoid(fx);
    half hy = half(fy);

    xs1.push_back(fx);
    ys1.push_back(fy);

    xs3.push_back(float(hx));
    ys3.push_back(float(hy));
}
```

Here are the results (looking at zoomed in portions of the graph this generates with a window width of 2.2 and a window height of 0.02 units):

When looking at the floating precision graph, {xs1, ys1} both of the corners of the sigmoid function are smooth:
[image][image]

However, when looking at the half precision graph {xs3, ys3} the corner in the positive x axis shows a stepping effect while the corner in the negative x axis shows a lower resolution but smooth graph:
[image] [image]

I am not sure why this is happening since the only difference between positive and negative numbers should be a sign bit.

Is there something wrong that I am doing or is this a flaw in the half library?

Comment: Isn't it the case that sigmoid values are [0;1]? So it is perfectly normal, that around 1, the precision is much lower than around 0.

Comment: Oh you are right! I tried it translated and saw the step effect show up on both sides. Feel free to write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Sigmoid function output values are [0;1], so what you see is normal: in the bottom picture, values are around 1, so precision is much lower than around 0.